# Base column labels in dataframes are unnecessarily long and bloated

Tags: r

It happens whenever I'm trying to define some data column in dataframe, e.x.

```
desc_labels <- c("N", "Mean", "Median", "Min", "Max", "Q1", "Q3", "Range", "QRange", "SD", "CV", "SE")
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

It happened after I jumped from Manjaro to Arch. Did a pretty common installing process - necessary libraries, plugins, etc, just as usual.

This is really annoying. Any ideas?

The full code looks like this:
I have a dataframe with values and I'm counting descriptive statistics for it.

```
desc_stats <- data.frame(desc_labels <- c("N", "Mean", "Median", "Min", "Max",
                                          "Q1", "Q3", "Range", "QRange", "SD",
                                          "CV", "SE"),
                         stats <- c(subj_num, mean_value, median_value, 
                                       min_value, max_value, quar1, quar3,
                                       val_range, quar_range, stdev, val_cv,
                                       val_se))
```

Comment: There must be more code to show than just defining this `desc_labels` vector - can you show how you are assigning this to the column label?

Comment: I cannot replicate this.

Comment: `data.frame(desc_labels = ...)` should be used instead of `data.frame(desc_labels <- ...)`

Comment: Do not use `desc_labels <- c(...)`; it should be `desc_labels = c(...)` with an equals sign. You are naming a parameter not creating a variable.